# Check date if matching then send yes to stringbuilder in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to send schedule for today's deployment so for that I am trying to comparing the dates  and if date matches then it should "YES" to stringbuilder and if it doesn't match then it should send "No" to stringbuilder respectively. For that **I have written groovy script for Jenkins** likewise-

```
                    echo "FIT2 Deployment started"
                    if(runConfig.FIT2Deploy){
                        FIT2Deploy = sb.append(padToLength('FIT2', 15)).append('|')
                    }
            }
            stage('Log Intent') {
              echo runConfig.stringify()
            } 

           String makeMarkFor(boolean bool) {
              return (bool ? "Yes" : "No")
           }
           class RunConfig implements Serializable {

    String padToLength(String initialValue, int length) {
        String tmpVal = initialValue
        while (tmpVal.length() < length) {
            tmpVal = tmpVal + " "
        }
        return tmpVal
    }

    String centerPadToLength(String initialValue, int length) {
        String tmpVal = initialValue
        boolean atFront = false
        while (tmpVal.length() < length) {
            if (atFront) {
                tmpVal = " " + tmpVal
            } else {
                tmpVal = tmpVal + " "
            }
            atFront = !atFront
        }
    }

    String stringify() {
        def sb = StringBuilder.newInstance()
        sb.append('The following is the schedule for today ').append('|')
        sb.append('\n================================\n')
        sb.append(padToLength('Environment', 15)).append('|')
        sb.append(padToLength(' Deploy', 8))
        sb.append('\n--------------------------------\n')

        //sb.append(padToLength('FIT2', 15)).append('|')
        sb.append(centerPadToLength(makeMarkFor(FIT2Deploy), 8))
        sb.toString() 
        }
}
```

But **It is not working** can someone please help me? I am expecting output-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change `padToLength('Environment', 15)` to `'Environment'.padRight(15)` and get rid of your `padToLength` method

You can change `centerPadToLength(makeMarkFor(FIT2Deploy), 8)` to `makeMarkFor(FIT2Deploy).center(8)` and get rid of your `centerPadToLength` method

And then looking at your code, you probably want `makeMarkFor(runConfig.FIT2Deploy).center(8)`, but it's hard to tell as the logic is a bit complex with the same variable names used in different context